# MdBootstrap with Angular

Tags: angular, material-design, bootstrap-4

How to make bootstrap material design with Angular.

Here is what i have tried so far .
I am using cli to build my angular project.

angular-cli.json file

I have installed MDB using npm and added these to my angular cli json file.

```
"styles": [
        "styles.css",
        "../node_modules/mdbootstrap/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/mdbootstrap/css/mdb.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/jquery-3.1.1.js",
        "../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/tether.js",
        "../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/bootstrap.js",
        "../node_modules/mdbootstrap/js/mdb.js"
      ],
```

Now i add the code to the component.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Warning</button>
```

The code throws no error but the click wave and click are not functioning. Please help

Answer (score 12):

To use mdbootstrap in Angular you should install the *Angular version* via npm:

`npm i angular-bootstrap-md -save`

FontAwesome is used as well, so be sure to add it to your styles:

`"../node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss"`

And finally, in your **app.module.ts** you need to include:

```
import { MDBBootstrapModule } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
   ...,
    MDBBootstrapModule.forRoot()
  ],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

See more on their github page:

https://github.com/mdbootstrap/Angular-Bootstrap-with-Material-Design

Comment: @Z if i dont want to use the angular way just using the external javascript like in angular we import external js libs is that possible?

Comment: I'll test it and let you know shortly. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use the Angular version? It's the exact same thing, but built for easy import into Angular-CLI projects.

Comment: Yes i dont want to use any external modules that is reason. Thanks fpr helping please let me knw

Comment: Went through all the possibilities and animations will not work without the angular module integration. Angular appears to be prevent any animation from being called (likely to prevent cross-reference animation which cause browser crashing). Sorry it's not the answer you were looking for.

Comment: @Z.Bagley I used the method on that github page, but animations still does not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @MartinIngvarKofoedJensen Animations aren't implemented by default for this library. You'll need to use their custom css animations as documented here: https://mdbootstrap.com/angular/css/animations/

Comment: Is your problem solved?
https://mdbootstrap.com/support/mdb-and-angularjs/

Comment: one is `angular-bootstrap-md` and another one is `mdbootstrap`.
for second one, Do we have to do `npm i --save bootstrap`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed the npm package, and configured it correctly (see [here](https://github.com/mdbootstrap/Angular-Bootstrap-with-Material-Design#how-to-install-mdb-via-npm)), you just need to add the **mdbRippleRadius** directive in button tag, like this:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" mdbRippleRadius>Warning</button>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just execute this command, it will automatically add the required paths in the configuration file.

```
ng add angular-bootstrap-md
```

Comment: Good first answer, however your answer assumes that the user has this `ng` command line installed. Please consider explaining those assumptions in the future